# Go: command line flags

Tags: go

I know you can specify command line flags and run your binary file against them like this:

```
./binary -output=html -type=doc
```

However, I was looking at the implementation of this Go package: https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata

I'm wondering how the author is able to enable the user to run the commands like this

```
go-bindata /data
```

instead of

```
./go-bindata -target=/data
```

Appreciate some help in case I missed out anything!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to use `flag.Args()` which is, simply, the non flag arguments following the flags. You can either fetch the entire list, or get a specific arg with `flag.Arg(i)`. See http://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Args

And from the source of the program you posted:

```
// Create input configurations.
c.Input = make([]bindata.InputConfig, flag.NArg())
for i := range c.Input {
    c.Input[i] = parseInput(flag.Arg(i))
}
```

Comment: what about go-bindata without ./go-bindata?

Comment: @user3918985 for that you'll have to just install the executable in your PATH, it has nothing to do with Go. you can just add `$GOPATH/bin` to `$PATH` and you'll have every installed go executable ready.

Answer (score 1):

Easy as pie using the [flag](http://golang.org/pkg/flag) package. Checkout [flag.Args](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Args)